# Mapping cones and resolutions

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let me preface my question by acknowledging the vagueness of it.  I am hoping to find some information in the form of references as opposed to a hard and fast solution.

Suppose that $S=k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $I$ is an ideal of $S$.  Let $M$ be an $S/I$-module thought of as an $S$-module.  Suppose $F_{\bullet}$ is a (minimal) free resolution of $M$ (again, as an $S$-module).  What I am interested in is knowing how the resolution of $I$ fits into the situation.

I know that I can resolve $I$ and $M$ as $S$-modules, and they simply differ by one dimension, so it seems like a mapping cone might be lurking around.

Searching for resolutions and mapping cones only brings up recent results of Herzog, et al, and those results are much more specific than I think I need.

Any information on the subject would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $M/I$? And what are different by one?

Comment: That was a typo, it should have just been $M$.  The resolutions of $M$ and $I$ would be identical up to a shift in degree by one.

Comment: Why are they identical up to shift? Is $M$ isomorphic to $S/I$ or any $S/I$-module?

Comment: This question is pretty vague.  What exactly are you asking?  You can say something about the vanishing of Tor_S(M,-) and Ext knowing that $M$ was pulled back from an $I$ module.  You can use F with the resolution of I to make a free $S/I$ module resolution.